# Woocommerce - How to send custom emails based on payment type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, payment-method

Here is the problem. My woocommerce website has 3 different payment options -

- Check Payment
- Western Union
- Cash On Delivery

If my buyer checkout with "Check Payment" I want to send him an automated email that outlines the steps to make a check payment. 
If he checkout with "Western Union" I want to email him my Western Union information as an automated email. 
Another automated email should be send for Cash On Delivery.

Usually in Woocommerce you have a single email sent to customer for all completed orders, in my case I need 3 different emails depending on the payment option.

So I started using this tutorial to make a custom email - https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

The tutorial above is used to make custom emails for expedited shipping. This is the line of code used for the same from the tutorial -

```
// bail if shipping method is not expedited
if ( ! in_array( $this->object->get_shipping_method(), array( 'Three Day Shipping', 'Next Day Shipping' ) ) )
    return;
```

What will the line of code be if I want to check what the payment method is? 
I want to check if the payment method is "Check Payment" so that I can send him a custom email.

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send a different customized email for each payment method with this custom function using thank_you hook. There is many options that you can set, for this refer to [wp_mail() function code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/).

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_cheque_payment_method_email_notification', 10, 1 );
function wc_cheque_payment_method_email_notification( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $user_complete_name_and_email = $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name . ' <' . $order->billing_email . '>';
    $to = $user_complete_name_and_email;

    // ==> Complete here with the Shop name and email <==
    $headers = 'From: Shop Name <name@email.com>' . "\r\n";

    // Sending a custom email when 'cheque' is the payment method.
    if ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cod' ) {
        $subject = 'your subject';
        $message = 'your message goes in here';
    }
    // Sending a custom email when 'Cash on delivery' is the payment method.
    elseif ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cheque' ) {
        $subject = 'your subject';
        $message = 'your message goes in here';
    }
    // Sending a custom email when 'Western Union' is the payment method.
    else {
        $subject = 'your subject';
        $message = 'your message goes in here';
    }
    if( $subject & $message) {
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
}
```

*This code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This is tested and it works.

---

***— Update —*** Related to your comments.

> Getting your available payment methods slugs *(temporary, just to get all slugs)*. This will display your available payment methods slugs on shop page or in product pages too. After usage, just remove it.
>
> Here is that functional code:
>
> ```
> function the_available_payment_gateways(){
>     foreach(WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways() as $payment_gateway)
>         echo '<div style="border:solid 1px #999">Method Title: "'.$payment_gateway->title .'" / Method slug: "'.$payment_gateway->id .'"</div>';
> }
> add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'the_available_payment_gateways', 1 );
> ```
>
> *This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Remove it after usage.*

Comment: Hey Loic, thanks for the code. I am about to test it and then I will accept the answer. One question, I have more than 3 payment gateways so I cannot use "else" for Western Union. Do you know how I can find what is the get_post_meta for Western Union (like "cod" or "cheque") ?

Comment: @Adam **Updated my answer** with a function that will display on shop page and on products pages all available payment methods slugs… Once done, leave me a comment here with those slugs, and I will update my code.

Comment: I will only test this code in 2 days but I will mark the answer because it looks like its correct. But thanks a lot Loic. If I have any doubts I will comment, but thanks again.

Comment: Hey Loic, I just tried your code in functions.php and its giving me an Error 500. Any idea why? I am still trying to resolve it.

Comment: Okay, its just because a curly bracket was missing in the last function. I edited it, its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

1) At first, you should ask WP question at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

2) In general, the easier way is to send an email, where is listed ALL options (divided with paragraphs, or even links), like this:

> Hello....
> .....
> .....
>   ===== Payment Methods ======= 
> 1) Western union    - follow this instruction: http://example.com/how-to-1 
> 2) Paid by check    - follow
>   this instruction: http://example.com/how-to-2 
> 3) Cash on Delivery -
>   follow this instruction: http://example.com/how-to-3
> .....
> .....

3) If you know a bit more,then here is listed all hooks - https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html (search for word EMAIL) and then customize the desired hook.

Comment: Sorry to inform you that all related questions around WooCommerce are off topic in wordpress stackexchange. So please update your answer. Thanks

Comment: @tazo I cannot send an email listing all options due to several reasons. I have to sen individual emails for the three different payment options.